# Google Analytics audience chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to compare 2 date ranges as it is possible with Google Analytics audience overview chart. Do you know an example with Highcharts or another JS chart library?

I am looking for the same chart with date ranges comparison, zoom (month, day, hour), with sales data.

[image: Google Analytics Chart]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking into [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) as well. It's highly customizable, open-source and free. I use it for a web store where it can track every possible variable and then have it presented in almost any way imaginable. There seems to be a fairly active developer community for various plugins/add-ons too.

Comment: Actually, it is not for website traffic analytics. I need the same chart as Google Analytics for sales data.